# Where to put class added via renderer2 in component.ts

Tags: angular

```
  togglePageCSS(toggle: 'add' | 'remove') {
    if (toggle === 'add') {
      this.renderer.addClass(
        document.querySelector('.app-header'),
        'app-header--fixed'
      );
    } else if (toggle === 'remove') {
      this.renderer.removeClass(
        document.querySelector('.app-header'),
        'app-header--fixed'
      );
    }
  }
```

I need to add a class to the header from a component. I used renderer to do this. The problem is I don't know which css file should i put the app-header--fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application has a `styles.css/scss` under `src`. It should be there.

One different approach can be achieved via creating a new `css/scss` file somewhere else and `@import "<path to your file>"`, so it is visible in your app's root.

So, all classes you wanna use with Renderer 2 should be global.